# Sql questions about self join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have question regarding SQL join for MySQL.

Let suppose I have following table A and parent-child relation ship.  How can I get all children (including sub children of children till leaf node)  given parent id ?

```
Table A
child id     parent id 
1            1
2            1
3            1
4            2
5            3
8            9
```

From the above table, if we given the parent (1) I have to query such that given the parent id(1) it gives all hierarchy example:

```
child id     parent id 
1            1
2            1
3            1
4            2
5            3
```

One of the restriction is I cannot change the data-model because the data model is JBPM databse tables (open source) I am adding some functionality  for ProcessInstancelog table in JBPM graph for sub-process (for each fan-out process).

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible in MySQL without the use of cursors / multiple queries.

Comment: It might be me, but I don't see what you want? "get all children given parent id", that would mean a simple `WHERE parent_id = x`. You second table looks the same, although missing the last row. Am I missing something? What do you actually want?

Comment: You want all children recursively?

Comment: In Oracle (and Postgres I think) you can do a hierarchical select all the way to the leaf nodes in a single query.  Not just the direct children, but children of those children, and children of those children's children etc.

Comment: @Magnus - is this a new thing in SQL Server 2008?  I wasn't aware of that.  Have you got a link?

Comment: There are at least 2 well-known approaches to represent hierarchies or trees with relational data: the adjacency list model and the nested set model. With both you'll need to maintain additional data. Both are widely discussed and researched. Not exactly on SQL but I discuss them in my blog here: http://novyden.blogspot.com/2008/01/managing-hierarchical-data-tree-in.html

Comment: You may review the concept of Nested set. It allows you to select the entire hieracy in one query.

Comment: Yes I need all children recursively....

Comment: @Steve In Sql server you can use either the [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) data type (2008) or a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) (2005)

Answer (score 1):

It appear that you want to be able to select a parent, and then get all of its children, regardless of where its at in the hierarchy.

The most efficient way is to use a reverse association table. In which each child would be associated with its parent, grant parent, and so on until you reach the root of the tree.

This obviously means you have to do more work on write to maintain the table, but it will save you from complexity on querying the table.

Example

```
id       parent
1        0
2        1
3        1
4        2
```

Reverse table

```
child     parent    level
2         1         1
3         1         1
4         2         1
4         1         2
```

With that you could do a subselect in your query with (select child where parent = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in sql like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nchar](10) NULL,
[managerId] [int] NULL,

)  

  WITH UserCTE AS (
    SELECT id, name, managerId,0 AS steps
     FROM dbo.[Employee]
     WHERE id = 1 

 UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.id, mgr.name, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
   INNER JOIN dbo.[Employee] AS mgr
     ON usr.managerId = mgr.id
)
SELECT * FROM UserCTE  order by id;
```